# Bought new computer, downloaded Ubuntu, want to wipe Windows 10 and get started

Tags: system-installation

I bought a new computer and downloaded Ubuntu. I want to wipe 
Windows 10 and get started with Ubuntu. What do I do first ?

Comment: See this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu and choose Erase disk and install Ubuntu in the installer

Comment: In case you change your mind, it is a good idea to start by making a backup image of Windows, or at least make a 'recovery disk', http://www.techradar.com/how-to/software/operating-systems/how-to-create-a-windows-10-recovery-disk-1302377

Comment: What brand/model system? Some easier than others. What video card/chip? UEFI install? How yo boot install media is then how it installs.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

Comment: This is a possible duplicate for sure, but if you update you question with what kind of hardware you have! is it UEFI or Legacy? then your question can be marked duplicate to a more specific question. or answers provided below will be more specific to **your** needs

Comment: The fact that you're asking this at all suggests that you're a Linux novice, so my advice would be to not wipe Windows but instead go for a dual boot solution, just in case you do actually need Windows in future. (e.g. firmware updates etc may have WIndows-only utilities)

Answer (score 0):

Create a live USB of Ubuntu using universal USB installer which you'll get from pendrive linux.com.  Disable secure boot and fast startup before installing ubuntu. Boot using live USB by pressing the appropriate key on bootup (<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>) and click install ubuntu option. Check the internet connection and click on first option Erase disk and Install Ubuntu. That's it, in the next reboot you'd have your ubuntu working.